# Vite JS React run build on ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, apache, ubuntu, vite

I'm trying to run a dist build on a Ubuntu instance on the cloud, I would like to know what is the best to run it, for example, on the same instance I'm running a backend nodejs app with pm2, I know pm2 is mostly for backend services.

when I go to the Vite website, https://vitejs.dev/guide/static-deploy.html it doesn't seem to have a straight forward solution, since I want it to run in the background.

Can you run it with apache?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.